# calling elasticsearch from classic asp works against a simple search, but cannot get a complex search to work

Tags: elasticsearch, asp-classic, msxml

If I send a simple query to Elastic using the following code construct, in the response back I obtain my expected results:

```
webaddress = "http://localhost:9200/" + index + "/_search?q='hello world'"

set xml = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xml.Open "GET", webaddress ,False

xml.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode("elastic:elastic123")

xml.Send
```

Now if I want to send a much more complex query such that It's not practical or possibly even possible to place the query on a single 'q' parameter as above. i.e.

the query:

```
get myindex/_search
{
    "query":{"match": {"headline": "overseas territory"},
             "match" : {"bodytext": "british territory"}
            }
}
```

So I would build this up into a variable. lets call it mySearch

Then my webaddress becomes :

```
webaddress = "http://localhost:9200/" + index + "/_search"
```

and xml.send becomes :

```
xml.Send mySearch
```

mySearch gets ignored and I receive back a default first 10 records from the variable webaddress.

The above search term is built in the following way in script:

```
Function TermBuilder(query)

    dim queryArray
    dim termString

    queryArray = split(query," ")

    termString = "{ ""query"" :{"

    For i = LBound(queryArray) to UBound(queryArray)
        termString = termString + """match"": {""headline"": """ + queryArray(i) + """ } ,""match"": { ""bodytext"": """  + queryArray(i) + """},"

    next
    termString = mid(termString, 1, len(termString) - 1) 'remove trailing comma

    termString = termString + "}}"

    TermBuilder = termString

  End Function
```

How should I pass my complex search so that it is recognised. I dont have the luxury of curl

Comment: This isn't an XML question.  You'd have the same trouble using WinHttpRequest, directly.

Comment: @Bob77 what makes you think this is an XML question? I couldn't see any clue about that.

Comment: Did you change the method to _POST_? `xml.Open "POST", webaddress ,False`

Comment: This question was mis-tagged MSXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had a couple of issue's the first was that I needed to use a 'POST' as opposed to 'GET' also when I created my index, I created the properties using CamelCase notation, but in the index's _source property they were all lowercase. After deleteing the index and creating the properties using lowercase and reindexing the index, I'm now obtaining my desired records.

Comment: Well done and thanks for posting your eventual result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET? I don't know ASP so I can't help for correctness of your code.

But there is a client API for ASP.NET.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html

I think this will helpful. In my case I'm using ES client for PHP and works GREAT :)

Comment: NO, there is no .NET involved here. AS mentioned, it's classic asp. Otherwise yes, I'd be using this library

Answer (score 0):

***[Edit] The OP discovered that the case used in the naming of the index and search terms was important (see OP's answer on this page). Having fixed that the query began to operate.***

It appears that you are probably reaching the server but whatever you are sending is not a viable command. I am curious to see the actual value of the variable you have constructed because classic ASP uses double quotes as its string delimiter too.

However, it could be that your search string is incorrectly formatted. The [Definitive Guide Elastic search documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html)  is very detailed and provides many examples.

It is the documentation on multiple field searches, that leads ms to suspect  your query is incorrectly formed.

It seems that a search with [multiple-query strings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html) should include a 'bool' keyword.

Or perhaps the [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-match-query.html) query would be of use.

Without seeing your actual query string it is imposible to be definitive about the cause of your issue but hopefully this will suggest a way forward.

Comment: No this isn't the case. If I perform the search directly in Kibana, I retrieve the correct results

Comment: Ok, I've amended the question to include how the query is built up in code. I thought that the Lucene query would be enough.